# EWS Managed API: Fetch emails by search filter on DateTimeReceived

Tags: api, exchangewebservices, managed

While searching for items in the inbox that have been received after a particular time frame (as mentioned in the code below). It searches for the date but it is also returning the email with the specified timestamp. I want the emails only after the specified timestamp.

```
SearchFilter greaterthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
                    Convert.ToDateTime(lastUploadedEmailtimeStamp));

mailItems = inbox.FindItems(greaterthanfilter, view);
```

Not sure if anyone has faced any similar issues? Basically I want to search for items that were received after a particular `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232750/how-to-get-the-millisecond-part-of-the-datetimerecieved-field-of-emailmessage-us?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange stores the datetimes with a precision down to the Millisecond, EWS only give you a precision on datetimes to the second however the Searchfilters do have a precision of milliseconds with Date time. So if you datetime stamps your using only have a precision of seconds then you need to use something like this eg where you wanted all email that was received after 7:43 and 8 seconds

```
SearchFilter sfs = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.ParseExact("2014/12/29 07:43:08.999", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff", null));
FindItemsResults<Item> femaa = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,sfs, iItemView);
```

If you want to look at the actual precision on your messages you need to use a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi. You can then look at the PT_Systime value which are FileTime "8 bytes; a 64-bit integer representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601" see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157583(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen. SearchFilter.LessThan is working perfectly. I see issues only with GreaterThan Filter.

Comment: That behavoiur would be correct based on the precision of the date value your using in the filter

Comment: I had similar problem and this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46232911/965722 By default EWS use seconds as DateTimePrecision, You can set it to milliseconds, so DateTimeReceived will include Milliseconds. Hope this helps!