# Find items between two timestamps in EWS

Tags: xml, date, soap, exchangewebservices

By using the [Query string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693615(v=exchg.150).aspx)-parameter in the [FindItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa566107(v=exchg.150).aspx)-operation, I can find items between two dates, like so:

```
<QueryString>Received:01/01/2001..01/15/2001</QueryString>
```

Is there any way to be more specific than this, in order to find items between two timestamps with second accuracy?

I've tried ISO-formatted date strings and seconds since the epoch, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Indexed search AQS or KQL you only have precision to the Date if you use a SearchFilter you can go to the second see [EWS Managed API: Fetch emails by search filter on DateTimeReceived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679099/ews-managed-api-fetch-emails-by-search-filter-on-datetimereceived)

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen. Exactly what I needed.