# How to get the millisecond part of the DateTimeRecieved field of emailmessage using EWS managed APIs

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have a code which synchronizes with exchange and gets the emailmessage objects for the given itemids:

```
List<EmailMessage> emails = new List<EmailMessage>();
            ServiceResponseCollection<GetItemResponse> response =
                            MyExchangeService.BindToItems(MyItemIds, PropertySet);
            foreach (GetItemResponse getItemResponse in response)
            {
                if (getItemResponse.Item != null)
                {
                    emails.Add((EmailMessage)getItemResponse.Item);
                }
            }
```

Now, the `emailmessage` object that I get as a result, contains the `DateTimeReceived` property as `9/15/2017 5:27:16 AM` whereas I would like it to contain the millisecond part of the time as well. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the precision on the ExchangeService class see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.datetimeprecision(v=exchg.80).aspx to millisecond before you make the call

Comment: Good addition, forgot about that.

Comment: You are my life saver!

Answer (score 1):

`.DateTimeReceived` is a normal `DateTime` field, so you have `Ticks` and every other standard way to analyze that value.

In your case,

```
message.DateTimeReceived.Millisecond
```

should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: It gives me 0 always.

Comment: Thanks, your answer combined with Glen's works like a charm :)